# Can Eclipse debugger display/set "virtual" fields via getters/setters?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

We have a set of classes that contain many "virtual fields" where the actual storage for each "field" is an array element with a non-obvious index, and the "field" is always accessed by getter/setter.  When displaying an object of this kind, it would be nice to have "virtual fields" displayed that look like normal fields but use the getters/setters for access.

Detail formatters, AFAICT, don't really provide a way to do this.

If I could even just get read-only support (no setters) for this, it would help.

I'm hoping (probably vainly) for a solution whereby we could use some kind of config file or process or even maybe plugin to set this up for all of these classes.

Answer (score 1):

[Logical Structures are what you need](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug_FAQ#What_are_logical_structures.3F). So I have this class

```
public class Something {

    public String[] fields;

    public Something(final String[] fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
    public String first() {
        return fields[0];
    }
    public String second() {
        return fields[1];
    }
}
```

Then you can go into Preference > Java > Debug > Logical structures and add your class and the fields with the corresponding getter methods like so

[image: adding logical structure]

This will then result in the debug window looking like this

[image: Debug variables]

If it doesn't then make sure the Logical structure button is selected (the yellow arrow pointing to a tree structure)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is to implement toString() such that the virtual fields' values are returned as part of the string in a readable format.  This might not scale to lots of "virtual" fields, but it's a helpful debug technique (usually).  When you select an object in the debugger its toString() result is displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said - we're doing that already.  With dozens of fields, it gets unwieldy.